# Select one file as favourite

Tags: android

My app has a **read me** button By clicking it, it shows many read me files with different languages like "read me-En", "read me-ru", "read me-ja", etc., User can select the file according to his language, for each read me file I have included an option to make it as **favorite**,

Now my point is, if the user selected one read me file as his favorite one...

1. From the next time whenever the user clicks on the read me button then only his favorite read me file should be visible...

How can I do this?

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to store your favorite "read me" file.

Answer (score 1):

It's logic stub. You can keep selected or favorite file on SharedPreference or SQLight etc.. and next time when every you click on button you have to show that file or filter by that files.

You want coding help. Please share your code.